# Using sympy to evaluate a double integral

Tags: python, sympy

I want to write some code to evaluate functions, in terms of x and y, using a double integral. The lower boundary of both the inner and outer integral being -1 and the upper boundary being 1 for a given function.

Here's the code I tried to use to get to evaluate an example polynomial:

```
import sympy

example_poly = sympy.Poly(x/2-y**2,x,y)
a = sympy.integrate(example_poly, (x, -1, 1))
b = sympy.integrate(a, (y,-1,1))
print(b)
```

However, I just get an error saying 'GeneratorsNeeded: can't initialize from 'dict' without generators' pointing at the following line:

----> 5 b = sympy.integrate(a, (y,-1,1))

What's going wrong here?

Comment: what is `symbolicFn`? could you please provide the COMPLETE back trace?

Comment: In the first integrate term I had `symbolicFn` where `example_poly` now is, it has now been edited.

Comment: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/18613

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to use the `Poly` class to integrate polynomial expressions:

```
In [13]: example_poly = x/2-y**2

In [14]: example_poly
Out[14]: 
x    2
─ - y 
2     

In [15]: integrate(example_poly, (x, -1, 1), (y, -1, 1))
Out[15]: -4/3
```

Unless you know of some reason why you should use `Poly` rather than ordinary sympy expressions then my advice is not to use `Poly`. The `Poly` class is used internally by sympy in order to compute things like integrals but you do not need to use it just because your expression looks like a polynomial.